# Extracting commands from preamble that have been called in file

Tags: packages, preamble

My LaTeX files are organised something like this:

- There is a file called `commands.tex` containing all the custom commands I use, mostly mathematical symbols, operators, etc.
- Each of my other `.tex` files have `\input{(path-to-)commands}` in its preamble. Whenever I need a new command in any of these files, I just define it in `commands.tex` -- there are a lot of symbols I use over and over again, and this saves me from defining them each time.

I now want to share one of my files -- let's call it `main.tex` -- as a single self-contained `.tex` file.
The simple thing to do is just copy `commands.tex` entirely into `main.tex`, but then the preamble would be far longer and more redundant that it needs to be! Hence the question:

> **Question.** Is there a package/method that can detect which commands from `commands.tex` have been called in `main.tex`, and automatically extract *only* those commands into either `main.tex` or a new file?

I'm hoping for something that works like the [extract](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract) package, which does a great job of extracting content from one document into another, but doesn't do what I want here as far as I know.

Comment: Related: [Producing self-contained source?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/377826) and [How do you store all your TeX files long-term?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/42052).

Comment: I used the following strategy: comment out all definitions (in your case the call to `commands.tex`), compile and then uncommenting the ones that were needed until the compilation is successful. I so reduced a 250 line preamble to less than 50. Usually, in case of received documents, I first changed all wrong definitions such as `\def\c{\gamma}`

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i haven't any suggestion that's more effective than what has been proposed by @egreg, but i want to commend you for wanting to streamline your file in this way.  too many authors don't, causing great difficulty for journal copyeditors trying to prepare manuscripts for publication.